# Why MediaMetaDataRetriever is taking so much time to retrieve Album Art?

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

I have a function from which I retrieve Album Art of all audio files. The problem is, though that it takes atleast a minute to retrieve the album art of 100-200 audio files. How can I make it take less time for retrieving album art??

```
private Bitmap getAlbumImage(String path) {
        android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(path);
        byte[] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
        if (data != null) return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Look into how to make multiple requests in parallel (my guess is not more than 5-10 would be a good spot), instead of one after the other.

Comment: What are you trying to say? I cant understand @adamsmooch

Comment: This function gets 1 image. You are callin it in a loop, yes? See how in Java you can have 5-10 parallel threads, all fetching different images.